# facebook log out

Tags: php, facebook

i have made one site in which i  have given functionality called 'connect with facebook'. it works fine for login..

but now i want to implement functionality when i click on logout, it should be logged out from facebook as well...

can any one tell me from where i should start..?

Answer (score 0):

[FB Logout](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/) says that calling FB.logout will log out the user.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement facebook logout using `FB.logout`, make sure its not redirecting before completing the logout action. I have done something like this.

```
$('#logout-link').click(function(){
        var loc = $(this).attr('href')
        FB.logout(function(response){
                location.href = loc;
        })
        return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<fb:login-button perms='email' autologoutlink='true'></fb:login-button>`. And then capture the logout event and simply redirect user to some where you can also logout from your system. 
When user will click the fb:logout you can capture that event at this function

```
FB.Event.subscribe("auth.logout", function(response)
 {
  // redirect user to that page where you logout from your system
  });
```

simple ;-)